# Inconsistent Object Displayed in Google Dev Tools

Tags: javascript

I console.log an object and I am confused, because in the first line the x- and y-value are different from the values that are displayed inside. What is wrong?

JS

```
{ 
 x: ...
 y: ...
 x-home: ...
 y-home: ....
}
```

[image: screenshot of dev tools]

Comment: Is there a `toString()` function on this object?

Comment: toString shouldn't affect it here, the dev tools have their own internal methods for serializing objects. toString would be responsible for `[Object object]` style output.

Is it possible that the object simply changes between the preview and you expanding it?

Comment: @DanPrince Prince, that could be, I will check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome dev tools won't freeze the object when you log it. When it renders the first time it checks the values and that's what you see on the preview line.

If you type.

```
var a = { b:3, c: 4, d: 5, e: 6, f: 7, g: 8 };
```

You'll get

```
Object {b: 3, c: 4, d: 5, e: 6, f: 7…}
```

Change one of the properties:

```
a.b = 10;
```

Then expand the preview of the last log and the dev tools will render the current state of the object with `a.b === 10`, even though it had already shown you the preview with `a.b === 3`.

So if your x property changes between you logging it and you expanding the preview, that should explain why.